# C# how to linq.select

Tags: c#, linq

i want to do the following i have variables stored in an int array called Straight i want to use Linq and get all the values when divided by 4 return 0 i tried this but it will only give me some bool variables and I'm not sure why

```
var a = Straight.Select(o => o % 4==0).ToArray();
```

any help is appreciated also i want to note that I'm still learning c# and Linq is something completely new to me

- also i want to be able to check the length of the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you're looking for is `Where` and not `Select`.

```
var a = Straight.Where(o => (o % 4) == 0).ToArray();
```

`Select` projects your list into a new returns type which in the case of the expression `(o%4) == 0` is **boolean**.

`Where` returns you the same object that fulfill the desired expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Where`, not `Select`

```
var a = Straight.Where(o => o % 4 == 0).ToArray();
```

`Select` creates a projection. In your example, it turns each element of `Straight` into a `bool`.